# Globalization: translate property TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName

Tags: c#, globalization

How can I translate `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName`
to english if current system language is something else?

Setting `CurrentUICulture` to "en-US" does not help.
Any suggestions?

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.standardname?view=netframework-4.8) say _"The display name is localized based on the culture installed with the Windows operating system. "_

Comment: okay this means I am probaly more or less without any chances

Comment: Just noticed this in the docs as well - _"If the operating system language is English, the value of the StandardName property is usually, but not always, identical to that of the [Id property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.id?view=netframework-4.8)."_ which _implies_ that if the OS language is **not** English, then the Id property will be the English name. Might be worth trying `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id`